# How to draw part of path between 2 points on google map?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to draw path between two points on google map but not the full path.

Scenario : Point A, Point B distance between  A and B is 100km.

I want to draw path on that route length 20km if I have covered 20 km.

Is that possible with Google Map?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, The technique of drawing path, is drawing line between two points several times. Lets say we want to draw path from A to D. We should draw line between A and B then B and C and lastly, C and D.

Google API has feature to provide points arrays for a requested path.

While drawing, you need to calculate distance between two points each time you draw a line. (Which is also simple because there is a API to do it.) Then you can break the loop whenever your criteria is gained.

Good luck there.

Comment: my point is how i will identify the second point at 20 km on the route A-B

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the drive or walking time on Google maps you have to make use of the Direction API's provided by Google. The API call for the Direction would would something like this:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Chicago,IL&destination=Los%20Angeles,CA&sensor=false
```

And you can embed that inside a class where you would make an http call using AsyncTask which would look like this:

```
GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json");
url.put("origin", origin);
url.put("destination", destination);
url.put("sensor",false);
```

Please follow this tutorial [this](https://ddewaele.github.io/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock/part5)  in order get the direction API (that includes driving, transit. walking and bicycling direction on your maps. )

Hope that would help!!!

Comment: origin= Chicago,IL&destination = Los Angeles,CA
will i can display this path.
but i also want to display a path in some other color that the user covered until now.
e.g he is 5 km away from his destination.

Comment: Yes. Process API data with your destination marker on the APP to get the remaining distance.